# Prove that $1-3^x+5^x-7^x = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$

Tags: calculus

**Problem :**

Prove that equation $$1-3^x+5^x-7^x = 0$$

has unique root $x=0$.

---

Since $\lim_{x\to-\infty}(1-3^x+5^x-7^x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-3^x+5^x-7^x) = -\infty$,

I tried to show $x \to 1-3^x+5^x-7^x$ is decreasing function, but it wasn't easy to determine its derivative is negative.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: If $x > 0$ then $3^x > 1^x$ and $7^x > 5^x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$1-3^x+5^x-7^x = 0 \iff 1+5^x = 3^x+7^x$$

Since the exponential functions involved are increasing functions we have the following inequalities.

$$x>0\implies 3^x+7^x > 1+5^x$$
 and $$x<0\implies 3^x+7^x < 1+5^x$$

Thus the equality happens if and only if  $x=0$

Answer (score 0):

$$1-3^x+5^x-7^x = 0$$
$$\rightarrow0\geq 1-3^x=7^x-5^x \geq 0 $$
$$\rightarrow0= 1-3^x=7^x-5^x = 0 $$
$$\rightarrow x=0$$

**EDIT**

If $x<0$ we'd get $$\rightarrow 0\leq 1-3^x=7^x-5^x \leq 0 $$